# Get absolute time difference between two rows of table into other table

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table with a time stamp and a boolean value indicating the presence of a thing that looks like this

```
id     timeStamp     thingIsIn
1      t1            1 
4      t2            0
5      t3            1
7      t4            0
```

where t1-t4 are just datetime values coming from the getdate() function when the table is populated. Since duplicates are deleted, I may have non-consecutive id's. I need to send the inTimes to a table and the outTimes to a table. An example of the inTimes table:

```
timeStamp     duration
t1             t2-t1    (this is the timeStamp of when it went in and how long it was there)
t3             t4-t3
```

where t2-t1 could be any length so I want the time in datetime, not a part of datetime.

How do I calculate the time difference and how do you send that to the new table?

Comment: SQL Server has `DATEDIFF` function to calculate the interval length

Comment: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )   I can't use a datepart, I need the total time difference in yyyymmddhhmmss.000

Comment: `mm` doesn't make much sense for an interval -- is it 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? Similar for `yyyy` -- leap year or not?

Comment: Is there not some way to perform t2-t1 without restricting to only one measure of time ie seconds or days? If my thing is in for 65 days, reporting days is helpful but I lose the accuracy or  hours and minutes etc. But what if my thing is only in for a few seconds, then the data is completely useless. Do I have to get each measure of time separately and then concatenate it somehow in an arduous process?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `datepart` can be as precise as nanoseconds. Isn't that precise enough? I doubt your timestamps are even precise enough to ask for more precision.

Comment: Ok, so do I get it in seconds or ms and then backtrack the days, hours, etc and cast it to a datetime and include this in the column? ... and how would I do that? (sorry new to sql)

Comment: What conversion do you have in mind for an interval to be a date/time? That just doesn't make much sense. Maybe a date/time can be seen as the interval from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0. If you mean that, you can use `dateadd()` to add the interval to 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0. But you'd likely need `datetime2` for that as `datetime` doesn't reach that far back.

Comment: The problem of converting elapsed seconds to months and years has nothing to do with SQL. You can easily convert seconds to hours and days, but not months or years. How many months are 62 days? How many years are 1460 days? It all depends on your domain. You can postulate, for example, that 1 year is 365.25 days, which is accurate enough in many cases.

Comment: The datetime datatype is NOT a measure of time. What would you expect if you received 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-02 as your date values? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I'm currently using an Excel macro to do this on our csv files. On the back end this is just a decimal so 4.5 is 4 days and 12 hours. I just perform the math t2-t1 and I get a decimal number which Excel allows me to display in my format of ddhhmmss. I know it doesn't make sense to talk about months due differences in length so I report it in days. The data is still just a decimal and its value is in yyymmddhhmmss.000 if you don't specify a different format. I guess I'll just get it in seconds and deal with the format when I export the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to use a window function to get the next record's value. The following query should work.

```
create table time_stamp
(
  id int,
  timeStamp DateTime,
  thingIsIn int
);

insert into time_stamp VALUES(1, getdate(), 1);
insert into time_stamp VALUES(7, getdate() + 4, 1);
insert into time_stamp VALUES(4, getdate() + 1, 0);
insert into time_stamp VALUES(5, getdate() + 2, 1);
insert into time_stamp VALUES(6, getdate() + 5, 0);
insert into time_stamp VALUES(8, getdate() + 3, 0);

SELECT t.timeStamp, DATEDIFF(hour, t.timestamp, lead_time) hour_difference
FROM (SELECT ts.id, ts.timeStamp, ts.thingIsIn, LEAD(timeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY timeStamp) lead_time
      FROM time_stamp ts) t
WHERE t.thingisin = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84db6e/9